# Get key and value from Nested Object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

I want to show the key and value from nested object with data :

```
const obj = {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "data1": {
      "label": "label1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "data2": {
      "label": "label2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

And want to show the data to object like this:

```
{data1: "value1", data2: "value2"}
```

I already try this:

```
  const init = Object.entries(obj.data).map(([key, value]) => {
    const data = `${key}: ${value.value}`;
    return data;
  });
```

But I got wrong format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `reduce` function

```js
const obj = {
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "data1": {
      "label": "label1",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "data2": {
      "label": "label2",
      "value": "value2"
    }
  }
}

const list = Object.keys(obj.data).reduce((acc, key) => {
   acc[key] = obj.data[key].value
   return acc
}, {})
console.log( list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array#reduce` for it.

```js
const obj = {success:true,data:{data1:{label:"label1",value:"value1"},data2:{label:"label2",value:"value2"}}};

const res = Object.entries(obj.data).reduce((acc, [key, obj]) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: obj.value,
}), {});

console.log(res);
```